# McCabe-style function complexity test for Mac

Tags: c++, macos, profiling, cyclomatic-complexity

What tool can I use to test McCabe-style function complexity of my code on Max OS X?

There is [pmccabe](http://people.debian.org/~bame/pmccabe/) for Linux, which is on my department's machines and what they want me to use. It analyzes each function in certain project files and spews out data for each, including function complexity as a McCabe-style integer ([example output](http://people.debian.org/~bame/pmccabe/sample.html)). I'd love something that has the same functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while to find this:

Use [homebrew](http://brew.sh).

Copy this line into a Terminal to install homebrew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Then, run this command:

```
$ brew install pmccabe
```

Answer (score 0):

Running a virtual machine on your Mac is free if you need access to pmccabe or other linux only tools such as valgrind.

You can download virtual box from https://www.virtualbox.org/

Here are some ubuntu images that came up from a quick google search: http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/

You might also look into ssh'ing into the university computers.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the possibility. I would like to know what tool I can use on OS X, per the question.

Answer (score 0):

pmccabe is available for Mac OS X.  It can be installed using Homebrew.

The link provided in the accepted answer is now outdated.  Try entering the following in Terminal to install Homebrew:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then enter the following command to install pmccabe:

```
$ brew install pmccabe
```

Once installed, use pmccabe as you would normally.  The following will output a complexity test for all .h and .cpp files in the current directory:

```
$ pmccabe *.h *.cpp
```